# create circle with 10 or more dashed border in css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Want to print a circle by using css or jquery with 6  or more dashed borders. Please see below image.[image]

Also the number of dashed are vary. it could be more than 10 or less than 10. The grey dashes are the number of remaining task & blue are the comped task.

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/X8528/)? Just modify the gray and blue variable to see the difference.

Comment: Yes.. it working for me but when I decrease the no of grey & blue numbers then it print octagonal. I tried to make changes on your code but not get success. Please suggest.

Comment: Yea, I think you reduced the total dashes to something around 8 or less right? Can you give a max and min number for the possible no. of dashes? We need to modify the circle's radius based on that.

Comment: Max number would be 20 & min number would be 2 for both grey and blue.

Comment: The total dashes Max is 20. & min is 1. Also if you can see the attached image there are white dashes with the same size in between two consecutive dashes.

Comment: Min should be atleast more than 4 because without that circular shapes would look very odd right you mean if you have only one element then you would get a full round?

Comment: yes..that right. If there in only 1 then it should be full round.

Comment: That is quite complex mate. Let me try.

Comment: did you get any luck. I also tried all possible angles. not got success.

Comment: No mate. All methods hitting the dead end.

Answer (score 0):

You can use border radius and border styling:

```
.circle {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 5px dashed red;
    background: black;
}
```

Here's a [JS Fiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/98C43/) that you can adjust to suit your needs.

Comment: Ok, but what about the number of dashes. its depend on parameter I passes. It could be 1,2 or 3 or more than 10.

Comment: Then you should update your question to reflect that, as that is not what you asked.

Answer (score 0):

According to my knowledge, You cannot do it with dashed borders.

> Note: There is no control over the spacing of the dots and dashes, nor over the length of the dashes. Implementations are encouraged to choose a spacing that makes the corners symmetrical.
>
> Note: This specification does not define how borders of different styles should be joined in the corner. Also note that rounded corners may cause the corners and the contents to overlap, if the padding is less than the radius of the corner.

Refer this - http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background